# Wordpress How to add custom field for all post of same category?

Tags: wordpress, post, categories, custom-fields

Add Custom Field "review_date" for All post of category "Testimonials"

I have added custom field for my category "Testimonials" and updated it and it is working.

But When i go to add new post of "Testimonial" category type then i have to again select new field "review_date". So how to display custom field for all type?

Any help should be appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85236/add-custom-field-to-all-posts-in-specific-category

Comment: when I add new post then should I get this new field on post?

Comment: Read the comments below the Answer on that link.. And just try it!

Comment: I will try and let you know.

Comment: @TheGoodUser Thanks for the help i have used Advanced Custom Field plugin and it works. Actually i have already used this plugin in my old project but i forget to use it.